# Luckily/fortunately

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

...but luckily/fortunately there was a lifeguard who saw what happened.

Could anyone please tell me if **luckily** and **fortunately** are equally natural to use in contexts like this or if one of them is more common?

Comment: There's no real difference in meaning, but [***against my expectations***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+luckily%2Cbut+fortunately&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20luckily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20fortunately%3B%2Cc0) Google NGrams shows that ***fortunately*** has always been more common in print. The gap is narrowing though, so I'd recommend to learners that they simply use the shorter (easier?) ***luckily*** in all relevant contexts.

Comment: My impression was polite people have good fortune (latin origin) and hoi polloi have good luck (german origin). This would make **fortunately** somewhat more formal, more likely to be found in print, and declining in usage.

Comment: Ngrams does not account for spoken utterances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,they are the same. They are not in the same register (level of speech).

However, in **everyday speech**, few would say fortunately unless their entire style of speech were very formal.

Comment: Bonus question: How about "unfortunately"? That's not as formal as "fortunately" is, is it?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately is used more often in speech.

Comment: Unfortunately is  probably  equally formal, but the meanings of unluckily and unfortunately are significantly different, and unfortunately has the more widely used meaning, both in writing and speech. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unfortunately https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unluckily

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent.
Years ago I heard this version

> Fortune favors the lucky.

of

> Fortune favors the bold.

which is

> [a] translation of a Latin proverb, which
> exists in several forms with slightly different wording but
> effectively identical meaning, such as *audentes Fortuna iuvat*,
> *audentes Fortuna adiuvat*, *Fortuna audaces iuvat*, and *audentis Fortuna
> iuvat*. This last is used by Turnus, an antagonist in the Aeneid.
> "Fortuna" refers to luck or its personification, a Roman goddess.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_favours_the_bold

That was long before its current incarnation:

https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Fortune_Favors_the_Lucky

Comment: @JavaLatte It's a (fixed) typo for "bold".

Comment: This is very interesting, I'm sure, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JavaLatte Agreed. But I think this site can be a place for language learners to learn a little more than they asked about.